# Generate and run Maven Kotlin jar

Tags: maven, kotlin, jar

I'm trying to generate a jar file of my kotlin project.
I read [Maven Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/maven.html#jar-file) and copied the code into my pom.xml but I don't understand what I'm supposed to insert at `${main.class}`.
Here is my [code architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vo7Eb.png) with MorisKt.java as my main class.

I tried *MorisKt.class*, */MorisKt.class*, *target/Moris.class*(container folder of my compiled code)

And nothing worked. The jar is generated but I have `Could not find or load main class` when I try to run it.

If you can explain me where I'm doing it wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put your main class file in a package and then reference it with the fully qualified name.

For instance if you put your Moris.kt in a package named app it would be :

```
<mainClass>app.MorisKt</mainClass>
```